# Module imported twice cause recreation on an object inside it

Tags: python, django

I have a Django project. A part from this Django project was a reporting module that searches for reports directory inside all INSTALLED_APPS, very similar to autodiscover mechanism of the admin interface.

This module had a small registery class that registers classes found. In a very simplified way it looks something like this:

```
def autodiscover():
    """
    Searches for reports module in all INSTALLED_APPS
    """

    global REPORTSLOADING
    if REPORTSLOADING:
        return
    REPORTSLOADING = True

    import imp
    from django.conf import settings

    for app in settings.INSTALLED_APPS:
        try:
            app_path = import_module(app).__path__
        except AttributeError:
            continue

        try:
            imp.find_module('reports', app_path)
        except ImportError:
            continue

        import_module("%s.reports" % app)
    REPORTSLOADING = False

class ReportsRegistery(object):
      .....

registery = ReportsRegistery()
```

If any of the INSTALLED_APPS need to register a Report class, we need a line inside `reports/__init__.py`:

```
import reports
reports.registery.register(SomeReportClass)
```

And inside the main urls.py i would do:

```
import reports
reports.autodiscover()


urlpatterns = patterns('',
....

 (r'', include(reports.registery.urls)),
)
```

Now I decided to create a pluggable django application for it and placed the same code in `__init__.py` of the package. The problem I am facing is that reports module with the new structure gets imported twice, thus causing the recreation of the 'registery' object. So, no urls are actually registered. It's loaded one time from the import inside urls.py (as expected) and another one initiated by autodiscover. I have verified this by:

```
print hex(id(registery))
```

and found out it returned 2 different values.

I thought that the reports package will be imported once just like when it was just a module.

How can I prevent it from being loaded twice ? Or how can I ensure that we will have only one ReportsRegistery instance to work with ?

Comment: That's not how importing in Python works; importing a module again just returns the existing module object. The only way you can get a module in the `sys.modules` structure *twice* is if it was imported under two different names, either through a symlink (`foo.py` pointing to `bar.py`) or if the module was used as the main python script (`python bar.py`), then later imported again (`import bar`); in that case the module lives as both `bar` and `__main__`.

Comment: And a pedantic nitpick you are free to ignore: it's spelled 'registry'. :-P

Comment: I assumed it was imported with a different name that why I checked the imports. According to the check I have made it's imported only twice, same name but different objects. And thanks for the pedantic check :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not uncommon for Django to import modules twice.  There are two reasons for this:

1. The classic Django project layout encouraged you to have your working directory on the path twice at two different locations.  This meant you could import something as `project.module`, or as `app.project.module`, which would confuse the import machinery.
2. The settings.py file is actually imported twice.

Fixes:

1. Double-check that all of your imports use the same style of path.
2. Don't import your module from settings.py

Comment: The module is not imported with different names according to my checks. Is there a way to print out what's importing the module just to make sure ?

Comment: Gah, really? With and without a nested namespace? Ugh.

Comment: I now changed to the imports to "projectname.reports" and it's working fine. Still don't know why "import reports" alone doesn't work!